# Sort array of object by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have this array of objects

```
[
  {
    '1485958472927784961': {
      name: 'bruno fiverr',
      points: 6,
      user_id: '1485958472927784961',
      tweets: [Array]
    },
    '1414575563323420679': {
      name: 'ju',
      points: 7,
      user_id: '1414575563323420679',
      tweets: [Array]
    }
  }
]
```

and I would like to sort this array by the number of points the user has.
I am trying to get it working using array.sort with the following function:

```
var top10 = array.sort(function(a, b) { return a.points > b.points ? 1 : -1; }).slice(0, 10);
```

but all I get is the same array from start. is that possible?

Comment: You have an extra backtick in ```.slice(0, 10`)```. That must be a copying error or you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: on my code it's normal,think stack changed it or something `.slice(0, 10);`

Comment: Your objects are not separate array elements. They array just has one element, and it's an object.

Comment: You could use `Object.values(array[0]).sort...`

Comment: @Barmar is it possible with that array or do I need to change everything?

Comment: this is an array with one object with values that are objects ---- what exactly are you trying to sort? show an example of the expected output

Comment: The sort function should be just `function (a, b){return a-b}` or `(a, b) => a - b` , otherwise you're treating `a < b` and `a == b` as equivalent when they aren't.

Comment: @skara9 I would like to sort those two values from there,first one with name bruno and second one with name ju by their number of  points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array with a single object whose values you want to sort by a property. For that you'll want to:

1. Access the first object in the outer array with `array[0]`
2. Extract the values of the object as an array with `Object.values`
3. Sort the values in descending order with the sort function `(a,b) => b.points - a.points`
4. Obtain your 10 elements with `.slice(0,10)`

```js
const array = [
  {
    '1485958472927784961': {
      name: 'bruno fiverr',
      points: 6,
      user_id: '1485958472927784961',
      tweets: [Array]
    },
    '1414575563323420679': {
      name: 'ju',
      points: 7,
      user_id: '1414575563323420679',
      tweets: [Array]
    }
  }
];

const top10 = Object.values(array[0]).sort((a,b) => b.points - a.points).slice(0,10);

console.log(top10);
```

Answer (score 1):

The outermost array is useless here. I would change your data structure to an object with key-values:

```js
const data = {
  '1485958472927784961': {
    name: 'bruno fiverr',
    points: 6,
    user_id: '1485958472927784961',
    tweets: [],
  },
  '1414575563323420679': {
    name: 'ju',
    points: 7,
    user_id: '1414575563323420679',
    tweets: [],
  },
};
```

From this you can just get all the values which becomes an array of the objects, then run a sort on that.

```js
const data = {
  '1485958472927784961': {
    name: 'bruno fiverr',
    points: 6,
    user_id: '1485958472927784961',
    tweets: []
  },
  '1414575563323420679': {
    name: 'ju',
    points: 7,
    user_id: '1414575563323420679',
    tweets: []
  }
}

const sorted = Object.values(data).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.points > b.points ? 1 : -1;
}).slice(0, 10);

console.log(sorted)
```